# Sharepoint server farm across WAN

Tags: sql-server, server-farm

I have a general question regarding Sharepoint setup. Currently, my company's setup is as follows:

1. Active Directory domain controller
2. SQL Server
3. Sharepoint 2010 server
4. Secondary AD Domain controller

These four are in four separate virtual machines all running Windows Server 2008R2.

Servers 1-3, are in the US, while server 4 is in Taiwan

I did not do the initial setup , but as our company grows, there is a need to create a mirror site where users in Taiwan will be able to locally read/write data and it will be synced to the US site, and vice versa.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I setup a separate SQL server / Sharepoint server in Taiwan, and clone the setup, including the database? How will these by synced?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199(v=office.15).aspx, a little down the page is Global solutions for SharePoint 2013

> Provides an overview of concepts related to deploying SharePoint 2013
>   in WAN environments. Summarizes WAN performance data and
>   optimizations. Illustrates supported architectures for deploying
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products geographically.